# Find string in Excel and use in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have different search strings arranged as one row after another in one particular column of a sheet. Another sheet of another file consists of other data. One column in that sheet shares almost the same strings as told in the former sheet but not in the same order. Hence my routine is to:

1. Copy  one string place in find option
2. go to the sheet in the file and the find option searches it for me
   the similar string.
3. As a mark to that one search is done i delete the search string
   after i have found it from this file.
4. Give a bold highlight to the parent sheet.

However this is tedious job for me because this routine i have to continue for atleast 10000 rows. Is there any vba code that with a click of a button or shortcut key i will get the above work done with just one go and not press several buttons

Comment: Can you edit the question to be a little more clear on what you need it to do?

Comment: You write the code and we fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can alter this a little bit to do the job:

```
Sub Find_First()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

This is where I found the above [code](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm).

You could use a loop to cycle through the master list like such:

```
blah = "."
j = 1
Do Until blah = ""
blah = Range("A" & j).Value
'Do whatever needs to be done here
j = j + 1
Loop 'then cycles through to the next row and does it again until the end of the data
```

And you can do formatting something like this:

```
Range("A" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 27 'Color:Yellow
Range("A" & j).Font.Bold = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by sorting both lists, do a Vlookup to apply a flag where there is a match, filter on the flag then delete and/or highlight.

No VBA code needed.